# Is there a mysqlnd plugin to authenticate using ed25519

Tags: php, mariadb, phpmyadmin

I setup my mariadb root user to authenticate using ed25519. Now I want to login using phpmyadmin but I'm getting the error `mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [client_ed25519]`.

After some searching I found that mysqli manage the authentication process via the mysqlnd extension. Then I searched through the output of `phpinfo()` and found the following line under the mysqlnd section:

**Loaded plugins**
mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password

As you can see there is no plugin for ed25519 authentication. After searching in the PECL repository and in Google I haven't found how can I get/setup/install a mysqlnd plugin for ed25519 authentication. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by installing libmariadbclient18:

`sudo apt install libmariadbclient18`

But am now stuck to use this authentication method with phpmyadmin.